# SQL Lite database not creating android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have a very simple code i am trying to create SQL lite database but it's not creating while i check my DEVICE FILE EXPLORER folder there is not any database folder there under my apps folder.
here is the code:
**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.ali.schoolapp;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Items " + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT, description TEXT)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.ali.schoolapp;      
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

}
}
```

Comment: It is created in Internal Storage do you have a rooted device? Or viewing via Android Studio?

Comment: yes I have created a virtual device i am using android SDK
i also checked Device file explorer > Data > Data > com.example.ali.schoolapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database will not get created until you attempt to do something with it. Only then (when getWritableDatabase or getReadableDatabase is called) will the database be created.

So you could try :-

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<<< EXISTING LINE
Cursor csr = myDB.getWritableDatabase().query("Items",null,null,null,null,null,null);
csr.close();
```

And then the Database would have been created.

- Note the above isn't how you would typically access the database, it's a quick fix. Normally you'd have you access methods in a Class (perhaps in the DatabaseHelper Class).

P.S. your `onUpgrade` method would very likely fail if you changed the version number (4th parameter (which is 1) when you call super). That is `onUpgrade` calls `onCreate` as the table exists you will get an error. You would typically [DROP](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) the table before calling `onCreate`).